# Flutter: Make a list item expand to a pop-up on press?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, animation

I have a list in my flutter app that displays some facts, I would like to make it so when I click any of the facts in the list, it animates, expands to a larger pop-up kind of screen that shows a the fact text and some buttons below like "save" inside the pop-up. Upon pressing "back" it should animate back to the list.

I have created an animation in a video editor to show the behavior I'm trying to achieve: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16GsJ1J89jn2CCVnuUecoy7VsF7BRdKF_/view?usp=sharing

Here's my build function currently:

```
// Main UI Build function
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: const PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50), child: FactsAppBar()),
        drawer: const FactsAppDrawer(),
        body: GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
          axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: ListView.separated(
            // Render List View
            itemCount: widgetsList
                .length, // Set item count from the previously generated list
            physics:
                const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (_, int index) =>
                widgetsList[index], // Build items from the generated list
            separatorBuilder: (_, div) => const Divider(
              // Build separator between the items
              thickness: 1.5,
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Note: The `widgetsList` is a list of the facts generated during the screen load.

Comment: Have you checked this one ? https://pub.dev/packages/animations#container-transform

Comment: @esentis I tried it but sadly it can't work with pop-ups, only full screen animations. I even found a github issue about it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104936